# OOP and DI in Java

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, solid-principles

There is some base class `BaseA` with lazy injected field `foo` (or not lazy).

```
public class BaseA {
  @Inject
  protected Provider<BaseY> foo;

  void someMethod1(){
   BaseY bar = foo.get();
   //...using "bar"
 }
}
```

Class `BaseY` was extended by class `DerivedY`:

```
public class DerivedY extends BaseY{
}
```

The base class `BaseA` was extended by class `DerivedA`. How can I use `DerivedY` instance in `DerivedA` class?

1st variant:

```
public class DerivedA extends BaseA {
  @Inject
  protected Provider<DerivedY> foo;

  void someMethod2(){
    DerivedY bar = foo.get();
    //...using "bar"
  }
}
```

But in this case FindBugs, for example, throws next violation "Class defines field that masks a superclass field (MF_CLASS_MASKS_FIELD)".

2nd variant:

```
public class DerivedA extends BaseA {
  void someMethod2(){
    DerivedY bar = (DerivedY)foo.get();
    //...using "bar"
  }
}
```

2nd variant requries using downcasting which is a violation of the Liskov substitution principle.

Which solution is right in this case (best practies)? What literature (or links) can you advise on this question?

Answer (score 1):

I advise researching [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). One solution to this problem could be a generic base class.

```
public class BaseA<T extends BaseY> {
    final Supplier<T> foo;

    public BaseA(Supplier<T> foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class DerivedA extends BaseA<DerivedY> {
    public DerivedA(Supplier<DerivedY> foo) {
        super(foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the BaseY just doens't resolve? Since DerivedY is the only subclass, will be used as @Default by the CDI. in BaseY you will get a DerivedY.